# Handling async callbacks in a for-in loop with DispatchGroup only works when all loops succeed

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

The code below is a rough sketch of the task. A database is queried, it returns a collection of results, that collection is looped in search of a specific property, if that property is found, a file storage is immediately queried and its async completion handler returns the file in the loop. Because I am handling async callbacks inside a for-in loop, I use a `DispatchGroup` to manage that. This setup works only if all of the documents in the collection have the `someIdentifier` property. If one document in the collection does not have the property, the dispatch group never calls `notify()` and we are stuck in limbo.

```
someDatabaseQuery.retrieveSomeData { (data, error) in

    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        return
    }

    // database has retrieved data, create dispatch group
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for document in data { // loop through collection

        // check if document has some identifier
        guard let someIdentifier = document["someIdentifier"] as? String else {
            return
        }

        dispatchGroup.enter() // identifier found, enter dispatch

        // perform async operation inside loop
        Filestorage.getSomeFile(forURL: someIdentifier) { (data, error) in

            guard let file = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }

            // download the file
            dispatchGroup.leave() // leave dispatch

        }

    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

        // all data grabbed, load table

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
guard let someIdentifier = document["someIdentifier"] as? String else {
    continue // this is the proper control flow statement
}
```

The problem was simply choosing the wrong control flow statement. When the guard failed inside the loop, `return` prevented the loop from finishing and never gave dispatch group a chance to notify. The else-clause in the guard should have been `continue`, which keeps control inside the loop (by letting it finish) and thus gives the dispatch group a chance to notify.

Comment: Good that you found the root cause. Btw, wouldn't you have to leave the DispatchGroup for the second guard as well? If not, when there is an error in retrieving the file, the group won't be notified.

<!-- language: swift -->
guard let file = data, error == nil else {
    dispatchGroup.leave()   // this has to be added?
    return
}

Comment: You are right and in the final version I implemented the defer method as mentioned by someone else to catch returns for any reason, including that guard. But somebody edited that part of my answer out.

Answer (score 3):

You must call `leave` if you call `enter`. But the `guard` inside the `getSomeFile` completion block can prevent the call to `leave` being made even though you called `enter`.

One solution is to use `defer` inside the completion block. Call `leave` inside the `defer` to ensure it is called no matter how you leave the block.